# Use remote database for azure mobile service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have stored my database on a server say abc.xyz.com
I want to use one of database from this server for azure mobile service.
How can I access this database from my mobile service.?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .NET backend of your mobile service, you can fairly easily use the external DB - since it uses Entity Framework as the default data access platform, you can use its tools to create the connection to your DB.

First, open the Entity Framework wizard to "Generate Model from Existing Database": right-click the project, select Add --> New Item --> ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and choose one of the options with from an existing DB (either "EF Designer from database" or "Code First from database"). The wizard will create a context class which you can use when implementing your tables.

Notice that you may need to implement some data mapping since to expose data in the `TableController<T>` classes you need the `T` parameter to implement the `ITableData` interface. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/27/bring-your-own-database-with-the-net-backend.aspx and the tutorial at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/ have more information on how to implement your scenario.